# Passing a user input to an ssh command

Tags: ssh, mysql, unix, shell

I'm currently trying to create a shell script that will execute a mysqldump on a remote mysql database and then copy the output file back to my local machine. The problem I'm running into is that I don't want to hard code the password into the script. I tried using 'read' to prompt for user input, but that variable doesn't seem to be getting passed to the remote command.

For reference, my script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
PASSWORD=""
TABLE=""
while getopts t: flag
do
   case "${flag}" in
      t) TABLE=${OPTARG};;
      *) echo 'invalid argument.'
   esac
done
read -sp "input the mysql password:" PASSWORD
#this is just to verify what the local and remote command is seeing
echo "$TABLE, $PASSWORD"
ssh myserver -p 9999 "echo $TABLE, $PASSWORD"
#this is the ssh command 
ssh myserver -p 9999 "mysqldump --xml -h somesql.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -u admin -p ${PASSWORD} mydb ${TABLE} > ${TABLE}.xml"
scp -p 9999 myserver:/${TABLE}.xml ${TABLE.xml}
```

If I run that script with

> ./data_input.sh -t mytable

it will prompt for a password, but not see the PASSWORD variable when the ssh command runs, and mysqldump will fail to authenticate. What is the correct way to pass along the user input variable to the ssh command?

Comment: Why you do not use `mysqldump` directly from your  host?

Comment: @RomeoNinov With the way the server is setup, I can't connect directly to mysql from the local. I need to ssh into the remote and run mysql from there. It is possible mysql could be configured to allow remote connections, but it probably isn't worth it for what we are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space between `-p` and the password variable, but according to the `mysqldump` man page:

> If given, there must be no space between --password= or -p and the password following it.

Comment: Nice catch! I'm so used to getting prompted to fill in a password I never even considered that.